# Upgrade NGX-Admin 7.00 Angular 11 to Angular 15.2.9

Tags: angular, angular11, scss-mixins, nebular, angular15

I have face some  modules not found issues after migrate Angular 11.0.9  ngx-admin dashboard  to Angular 15.2.9

earlier packages are this

```
"@angular/animations": "^11.0.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "11.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "^11.0.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.0.9",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.0.9",
    "@angular/router": "^11.0.9",
 "@nebular/auth": "7.0.0",
"@nebular/eva-icons": "7.0.0",
"@nebular/security": "7.0.0",
"@nebular/theme": "7.0.0",
```

but respective modules are at node_modules

even i tried with delete package-lock.json and node_modules and clear npm cache as well

i tried with downgrade nebular theme to  version 9.0.3 as well

but issue is not fixed

i followed [https://update.angular.io/?v=11.0-16.0][1] link as reference

during build and start the project i got following errors

**Error 1**

node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
╷
2 │ @import '~@nebular/theme/styles/theming';
│         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
src/app/@theme/styles/themes.scss 2:9                                      @import
src/app/pages/pages.component.scss 2:9                                     @import

pages.component.scss is looks like this

```css
   @import '../@theme/styles/themes';
    
    @include nb-install-component() {
      ::ng-deep router-outlet + * {
        display: block;
        animation: fade 1s;
    
        @keyframes fade {
          from {
            opacity: 0;
          }
          to {
            opacity: 1;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    $xs: 425px;
    $sm: 576px;
    $md: 768px;
    $lg: 1024px;
    $xl: 1200px;
    $xxl: 1440px;
```

@theme/styles/themes has theme module

it looks like this

```js
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
  NbActionsModule,
  NbLayoutModule,
  NbMenuModule,
  NbSearchModule,
  NbSidebarModule,
  NbUserModule,
  NbContextMenuModule,
  NbButtonModule,
  NbSelectModule,
  NbIconModule,
  NbThemeModule,
  NbTooltipModule,
  NbCardModule,
} from '@nebular/theme';
import { NbEvaIconsModule } from '@nebular/eva-icons';
import { NbSecurityModule } from '@nebular/security';

import {
  FooterComponent,
  HeaderComponent,
  SearchInputComponent,
} from './components';
import {
  CapitalizePipe,
  PluralPipe,
  RoundPipe,
  TimingPipe,
  NumberWithCommasPipe,
} from './pipes';
import {
  OneColumnLayoutComponent,
  ThreeColumnsLayoutComponent,
  TwoColumnsLayoutComponent,
} from './layouts';
import { DEFAULT_THEME } from './styles/theme.default';
import { COSMIC_THEME } from './styles/theme.cosmic';
import { CORPORATE_THEME } from './styles/theme.corporate';
import { DARK_THEME } from './styles/theme.dark';

const NB_MODULES = [
  NbLayoutModule,
  NbMenuModule,
  NbUserModule,
  NbActionsModule,
  NbSearchModule,
  NbSidebarModule,
  NbContextMenuModule,
  NbSecurityModule,
  NbButtonModule,
  NbSelectModule,
  NbIconModule,
  NbEvaIconsModule,
  NbTooltipModule,
  NbCardModule,
];
const COMPONENTS = [
  HeaderComponent,
  FooterComponent,
  SearchInputComponent,
  OneColumnLayoutComponent,
  ThreeColumnsLayoutComponent,
  TwoColumnsLayoutComponent,
];
const PIPES = [
  CapitalizePipe,
  PluralPipe,
  RoundPipe,
  TimingPipe,
  NumberWithCommasPipe,
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, ...NB_MODULES],
  exports: [CommonModule, ...PIPES, ...COMPONENTS],
  declarations: [...COMPONENTS, ...PIPES],
})
export class ThemeModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<ThemeModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: ThemeModule,
      providers: [
        ...NbThemeModule.forRoot(
          {
            name: 'default',
          },
          [DEFAULT_THEME, COSMIC_THEME, CORPORATE_THEME, DARK_THEME],
        ).providers,
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

theme.scss is looks like this

```css
// @nebular theming framework
@import '~@nebular/theme/styles/theming';
// @nebular out of the box themes
@import '~@nebular/theme/styles/themes';
// @import '~@nebular/theme/styles/themes/dark';
// @import '~@nebular/theme/styles/themes/default';

$nb-themes: nb-register-theme((
  layout-padding-top: 2.25rem,

  menu-item-icon-margin: 0 0.5rem 0 0,

  card-height-tiny: 13.5rem,
  card-height-small: 21.1875rem,
  card-height-medium: 28.875rem,
  card-height-large: 36.5625rem,
  card-height-giant: 44.25rem,
  card-margin-bottom: 1.875rem,
  card-header-with-select-padding-top: 0.5rem,
  card-header-with-select-padding-bottom: 0.5rem,

  select-min-width: 6rem,

  slide-out-background: #f7f9fc,
  slide-out-shadow-color: 0 4px 14px 0 #8f9bb3,
  slide-out-shadow-color-rtl: 0 4px 14px 0 #8f9bb3,
), default, default);

$nb-themes: nb-register-theme((
  layout-padding-top: 2.25rem,

  menu-item-icon-margin: 0 0.5rem 0 0,

  card-height-tiny: 13.5rem,
  card-height-small: 21.1875rem,
  card-height-medium: 28.875rem,
  card-height-large: 36.5625rem,
  card-height-giant: 44.25rem,
  card-margin-bottom: 1.875rem,
  card-header-with-select-padding-top: 0.5rem,
  card-header-with-select-padding-bottom: 0.5rem,

  select-min-width: 6rem,

  slide-out-background: #252547,
  slide-out-shadow-color: 2px 0 3px #29157a,
  slide-out-shadow-color-rtl: -2px 0 3px #29157a,
), cosmic, cosmic);

$nb-themes: nb-register-theme((
  layout-padding-top: 2.25rem,

  menu-item-icon-margin: 0 0.5rem 0 0,

  card-height-tiny: 13.5rem,
  card-height-small: 21.1875rem,
  card-height-medium: 28.875rem,
  card-height-large: 36.5625rem,
  card-height-giant: 44.25rem,
  card-margin-bottom: 1.875rem,
  card-header-with-select-padding-top: 0.5rem,
  card-header-with-select-padding-bottom: 0.5rem,

  select-min-width: 6rem,

  slide-out-background: linear-gradient(270deg, #edf1f7 0%, #e4e9f2 100%),
  slide-out-shadow-color: 0 4px 14px 0 #8f9bb3,
  slide-out-shadow-color-rtl: 0 4px 14px 0 #8f9bb3,
), corporate, corporate);

$nb-themes: nb-register-theme((
  layout-padding-top: 2.25rem,

  menu-item-icon-margin: 0 0.5rem 0 0,

  card-height-tiny: 13.5rem,
  card-height-small: 21.1875rem,
  card-height-medium: 28.875rem,
  card-height-large: 36.5625rem,
  card-height-giant: 44.25rem,
  card-margin-bottom: 1.875rem,
  card-header-with-select-padding-top: 0.5rem,
  card-header-with-select-padding-bottom: 0.5rem,

  select-min-width: 6rem,

  slide-out-background: linear-gradient(270deg, #222b45 0%, #151a30 100%),
  slide-out-shadow-color: 0 4px 14px 0 #8f9bb3,
  slide-out-shadow-color-rtl: 0 4px 14px 0 #8f9bb3,
), dark, dark);
```

style.scss is looks like this

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700&display=swap');

// themes - our custom or/and out of the box themes
@import 'themes';

// framework component themes (styles tied to theme variables)
@import '~@nebular/theme/styles/globals';
@import '~@nebular/auth/styles/globals';

@import '~bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/variables';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/mixins';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/grid';

// loading progress bar theme
@import './pace.theme';

@import './layout';
@import './overrides';

// install the framework and custom global styles
@include nb-install() {

  // framework global styles
  @include nb-theme-global();
  @include nb-auth-global();

  @include ngx-layout();
  // loading progress bar
  @include ngx-pace-theme();

  @include nb-overrides();
  
//  for all screens
 @include screenStyleChanges-overrides();  
//  for all table
 @include table-overrides();
};

@import '~@fullcalendar/common/main.css';
@import './base';
```

this is my package.json looks like

```js
    {
  "name": "ngx-admin",
  "version": "7.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/issues"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "conventional-changelog": "conventional-changelog",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- --configuration production --aot",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test:coverage": "rimraf coverage && npm run test -- --code-coverage",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "lint:fix": "ng lint ngx-admin-demo --fix",
    "lint:styles": "stylelint ./src/**/*.scss",
    "lint:ci": "npm run lint && npm run lint:styles",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "docs": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs",
    "docs:serve": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs -s",
    "prepush": "npm run lint:ci",
    "release:changelog": "npm run conventional-changelog -- -p angular -i CHANGELOG.md -s",
    "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 es5 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points --tsconfig \"./src/tsconfig.app.json\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@akveo/ng2-completer": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "15.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.9",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^6.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckbox": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckfinder": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-clipboard": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-easy-image": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-enter": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-indent": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-media-embed": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paste-from-office": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-select-all": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-typing": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-undo": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-watchdog": "^39.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-widget": "^39.0.1",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^6.1.8",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^6.1.8",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^6.1.8",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^6.1.8",
    "@nebular/auth": "^11.0.0",
    "@nebular/eva-icons": "^11.0.0",
    "@nebular/security": "^11.0.0",
    "@nebular/theme": "^11.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^4.3.5",
    "@xmldom/xmldom": "^0.8.10",
    "@yr/monotone-cubic-spline": "^1.0.3",
    "apexcharts": "^3.42.0",
    "bootstrap": "5.3.1",
    "ckeditor5": "^39.0.1",
    "core-js": "^3.32.1",
    "docxtemplater": "^3.38.0",
    "eva-icons": "^1.1.3",
    "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "luxon": "^3.4.2",
    "nebular-icons": "1.1.0",
    "ng-apexcharts": "^1.8.0",
    "ng-connection-service": "^9.0.3",
    "ng-particles": "^3.9.3",
    "normalize.css": "8.0.1",
    "pako": "^2.1.0",
    "pizzip": "^3.1.4",
    "roboto-fontface": "0.10.0",
    "rxjs": "7.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.6.7",
    "sass": "^1.66.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "svg.easing.js": "^2.0.0",
    "svg.filter.js": "^2.0.2",
    "svg.js": "^2.7.1",
    "svg.pathmorphing.js": "^0.1.3",
    "svg.resize.js": "^1.4.3",
    "svg.select.js": "^3.0.1",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "tsparticles-engine": "^2.12.0",
    "typeface-exo": "1.1.13",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "15.2.9",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.16",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.4.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.4",
    "@types/node": "^20.5.7",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "rimraf": "5.0.1",
    "stylelint": "15.10.3",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "4.9.5"
  }
}
```

my angular.json file is look like this

```js
    {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ngx-admin-demo": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "preserveSymlinks": true,
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/favicon.png"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "node_modules/typeface-exo/index.css",
              "node_modules/roboto-fontface/css/roboto/roboto-fontface.css",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css",
              "node_modules/nebular-icons/scss/nebular-icons.scss",
              "src/app/@theme/styles/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.min.js"
            ],
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "lodash",
              "zrender/lib/svg/svg",
              "zrender/lib/vml/vml"
            ],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "prod": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "staging": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.stg.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ngx-admin-demo:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ngx-admin-demo:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ngx-admin-demo:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.min.js"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "node_modules/typeface-exo/index.css",
              "node_modules/roboto-fontface/css/roboto/roboto-fontface.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
              "node_modules/nebular-icons/scss/nebular-icons.scss",
              "src/app/@theme/styles/styles.scss"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/favicon.png"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ngx-admin-demo-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "ngx-admin-demo:serve"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "ngx",
      "style": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "ngx"
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

please help to sort out this issue

Comment: drop the `~` in the imports.